# Telegraf to InfluxDB - JSON Nested object property

Tags: grafana, influxdb, telegraf

I've been struggling already for few days to get this one working. All the solutions that I found from people with same problem did not work for me.

I am parsing data from JSON file through Telegraf using [inputs.file] and using this data later on in Grafana from InfluxDB.

My problem:
All key-value pairs where value is in a form of a number are working as they should and are showing correctly in InfluxDB. However, all key-value pairs where value is a string or boolean are not working.

1. [processors.converter]
   I have tried it and no success, whatever example I have followed I am not getting any new fields in the InfluxDB, also logs from telegram are not showing any of the keys or values that I declare in the converter.
2. [inputs.file]-json_strings_fields
   I have tried to add json_string_fields as well, many examples how other guys did it and no success.

Part of my json:

```
 },
"electricChargingState": {
  "chargingConnectionType": "UNKNOWN",
  "chargingLevelPercent": 77,
  "chargingStatus": "CHARGING",
  "chargingTarget": 100,
  "isChargerConnected": true,
  "range": 205
```

From the above code I am getting "charginLevelPercent", "chargingTarget" and "range", **I cannot get** "ChargingStatus" and "isChargerConnected".

In telegraf [inputs.file] I tried, but without success:

```
json_string_fields = ["chargingStatus"]
```

Also, in [processors.converter] I tried, but without success:

```
   [[processors.converter]]

   [processors.converter.tags]
      string = ["chargingStatus*"]
      boolean = ["isChargerConnected"]

   [processors.converter.fields]
      tag = ["chargingStatus"]
      string = ["chargingStatus"]
      boolean = ["isChargerConnected"]
```

Thanks to everyone who spare some of their valuable time to help me find solution.

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `[[outputs.file]]` output plugin to see what your line protocol looks like. If you do not see the fields, then the parsing is failing and the processors are probably not going to help you. If you do see the fields in the processors, then something else might be up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem has been solved by using the underscores and in json_string_fields declare full path of the key-value pair. Hope this sort problem for someone else as well. For instance:

```
   json_string_fields = ["state_electricChargingState_isChargerConnected"]
```